# Ubuntu 20.04 : NVIDIA drivers update issue after unloading nvidia-drm and nvidia-modeset

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 20.04, graphics, nvidia-geforce

As the title states, I have encountered issues when updating my GPU drivers, and my screen stays black when using Ubuntu in graphical mode. Here's how it went :

I could not update my GPU's drivers using Ubuntu's update manager (it told me the drivers were installed manually and should therefore be updated manually, even though I never touched them) so I decided to do it manually : I downloaded the driver installer on NVIDIA's website and executed it.

```
sudo sh ./NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-450.80.02.run
```

I followed the instructions of the top answer to a thread (https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/440840/how-to-unload-kernel-module-nvidia-drm) and went in text-only mode (CTRL+ALT+F2)  to unload kernel modules `nvidia-drm` and `nvidia-modeset` which the installer told me were loaded with the error messages :

```
ERROR: An NVIDIA kernel module 'nvidia-drm' appears to already be loaded in your kernel.  This may be because it is in use (for example, by an X server, a CUDA program, or 
         the NVIDIA Persistence Daemon), but this may also happen if your kernel was configured without support for module unloading.  Please be sure to exit any programs    
         that may be using the GPU(s) before attempting to upgrade your driver.  If no GPU-based programs are running, you know that your kernel supports module unloading,   
         and you still receive this message, then an error may have occured that has corrupted an NVIDIA kernel module's usage count, for which the simplest remedy is to     
         reboot your computer.
```

and

```
ERROR: An NVIDIA kernel module 'nvidia-modeset' appears to already be loaded in your kernel.  This may be because it is in use (for example, by an X server, a CUDA program, or 
         the NVIDIA Persistence Daemon), but this may also happen if your kernel was configured without support for module unloading.  Please be sure to exit any programs    
         that may be using the GPU(s) before attempting to upgrade your driver.  If no GPU-based programs are running, you know that your kernel supports module unloading,   
         and you still receive this message, then an error may have occured that has corrupted an NVIDIA kernel module's usage count, for which the simplest remedy is to     
         reboot your computer.
```

The installer then indicated that a previous version of the driver was installed and should be removed, which I did by typing the commands the installer told me to type :

```
apt-get remove --purge nvidia-455
apt-get autoremove
```

I then was able to execute the installer, which indicated :

```
WARNING: Unable to find suitable destination to install 32-bit compatibility libraries. Your system may not be set up for 32-bit compatibility. 32-bit compatibility files will not be installed; if you wish to install them, re-run the installation and set a valid directory with the --compat32-libdr option.
```

I chose not to care about it and to restart the graphical interface with

```
systemctl start graphical.target
```

but the screen just went black. I figured I did something wrong, so I decided to remove the driver I had just installed with :

```
apt-get purge nvidia*
apt-get autoremove
```

and to reinstall the previous drivers with `sudo apt-get install nvidia-455`, but it did nothing to solve my problem.

My GRUB is set to `quiet splash nomodeset`.

Now when I start Ubuntu, the screen stays black forever. I can however go to the text console (CTRL+ALT+F2) and do everything that does not use my GPU from there, but the lack of a graphical interface is incapacitating. How could I solve my issue ?

Thanks in advance !